# Datagrid based on input from textbox and combobox

Tags: datagrid, actionscript

Part of the program I am creating includes having a drop down menu where the user can select a type of load, before inputting the position of the load. The load and position would then appear in a datagrid and as many as the user pleases can be added.

I am not very sure where I went wrong but this is my code:

```
function loadlist():void{
combobox1.addItem ( { label: "Choose a Load" } );
combobox1.addItem ( { label: "Point Load" } );
combobox1.addItem ( { label: "Bending Moment" } );
combobox1.addItem ( { label: "Uniformly Distributed Load" } );
combobox1.addItem ( { label: "Varying Distributed Load" } );
combobox1.addItem ( { label: "Nonlinear Distributed Load" } );
}

function loadbuttonclick (event:MouseEvent):void{
combobox1.removeAll();
loadlist();
trace("load");

//datagrid
var myTextFormat: TextFormat = new TextFormat();
myTextFormat.font = "Comic Sans MS";

var datagrid:DataGrid = new DataGrid;
datagrid.columns = ["Type of Load", "Position of Load"];
datagrid.resizableColumns = true;
datagrid.setRendererStyle("textFormat", myTextFormat);
datagrid.addItem(Load type: "combobox1.selectedItem.label", Load position: "loadposition.text");


addChild(datagrid);

datagrid.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, gridItemClick);

function gridItemClick (event:Event):void{
trace("The Selected Load is " + combobox1.selectedItem.label);
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be getting an error from this line, the syntax seems to be wrong:

```
datagrid.addItem(Load type: "combobox1.selectedItem.label", Load position: "loadposition.text");
```

- It's not an object, an object has to defined with curly brackets {}.
- Object keys can't have spaces when defined using curly brackets.
- You're trying to pass dynamic values as strings, you should write combobox1.selectedItem.label instead of "combobox1.selectedItem.label".

It's been a while wince I've worked with datagrids, but if I recall correctly, the item is an object, which keys should match the columns.

Since your columns include spaces you wouldn't be able to write:

```
datagrid.addItem({Load type: combobox1.selectedItem.label, Load position: loadposition.text});
```

However, this should work:

```
var object:Object = new Object();

object["Type of Load"] = combobox1.selectedItem.label;
object["Position of Load"] = loadposition.text;

datagrid.addItem(object);
```

I didn't have the time to test it, but that should be the right direction.

Comment: I tried that but got the error 'TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference'. Also, the column titles in the datagrid do not appear

Comment: combobox1.selectedItem or loadposition (or both) are null, you need to debug your code.